# Android VideoView wont play 720p hd video while device does support the format

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have a strange problem with the Android VideoView. I have tested the app on some devices and most of them don't have this problem. When i play a HD video my Galaxy tab 10.1 does not play the video while it should play 720p and 1080p hd videos. I check for each device if the video format is supported like this:

```
if(CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P)){
Log.i(TAG, "playing high quality video");
    uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myapp/raw/" + movieIndex[video]);
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "playing low quality video");
    uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.myapp/raw/" + movieIndexLow[video]);
}
```

But the tab just picks the high dev video. I do hear the sound but i don't see the video when i only use the lower quality video everything is working just fine.
Can anyone tell me what the problem can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See discussion at http://www.thegalaxytabforum.com/index.php?/topic/6999-h264-high-profile-movies. As many other Android devices, Tab 10.1 does not support H264 Main profile. The official [spec](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for Android only requires Baseline profile.